# Latency-based routing for multiple API Gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sagemaker

I want to serve an ML model on AWS.

Currently, I think it should look as follows:

- We use an API Gateway websocket connection ...
- that makes use of a Lambda function, that upon input ...
- Calls an ML model running on an AWS Inferentia Chip, which is exposed as an AWS Sagemaker endpoint.

Now, I think of getting the latency low globally.  Hence, I thought of the following:

- Replicate the whole setup for many regions.
- Do latency based routing for different users in different regions.

Could you tell me whether this approach makes sense or whether it should be done differently? If you consider this approach to be sensible, how would I do the latency-based routing in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing SageMaker endpoint APi Gateway -> Lambda -> endpoint is a good option. You can also consider using [mapping templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/) if you don't have any preprocessing/post processing in Lambda. Regarding latency based routing you can set that up in [Route53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-latency.html) to invoke corresponding region API.